# Create nib in bundle

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm new to ios, and can't get done pretty simple thing.

```
TableViewController *tableVC = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableView" bundle:nil andType:CONTROLLER_TYPE_FIRST];
ViewController *wizard = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WizardView" bundle:nil andtype:first];
UINavigationController *navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:wizard];
```

Init with tableVC, works. But if I initialize with wizard i get

```
'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/60750878-E595-4A24-B0B8-F65DA78128C0/kodinisRaktas.app> (loaded)' with name 'WizardView''
```

What to do with this bundle nib to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cases:

1. `ViewController` `doesnot have .xib` .
2. `ViewController does have .xib but its name is not 'WizardView'`.

Solution:

Case 1:

```
 ViewController *wizard = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

Case 2:

```
use correct name of .xib file
```